# Attachment pdf is not loading using Java Mail API on gae

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf, jakarta-mail

This code is used for dynamically sending pdf attachment to the email.
This code is to deploy on google app engine.
Code works (There is no exception and email is received) but the pdf attachment failed to load.

```
public class EmalTableServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        String sub = "You requested an Article";
        String to = "*********@gmail.com";
        String body = "hello";
        try {
            // String message = req.getParameter("data");

            email cs = new email(to, sub, body);
            cs.send();

            out.write("Email Sent Successfully");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

```
class email {
    String toAddress;
    String owner = "*****@gmail.com";
    String sub;
    String msg;

    email() {}

    public email(String email, String sub, String msg) {
        super();
        this.toAddress = email;
        this.sub = sub;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    void send() {

        String htmlbody = "<table style=\"width:300px\"><tr>  <td>Jill</td>  <td>Smith</td>  <td>50</td></tr><tr>  <td>Eve</td>  <td>Jackson</td>  <td>94</td></tr></table><br><br><a href=\"www.thotopic.appspot.com\">link</a>";  
        Properties p = new Properties();
        Session s = Session.getDefaultInstance(p, null);
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart htmlpart = new MimeBodyPart();
        System.out.println("<-------------------------------Mail Sent------------------------->" + toAddress);
        try {
            htmlpart.setContent(htmlbody, "text/html");
            mp.addBodyPart(htmlpart);
            Message mess = new MimeMessage(s);
            mess.setFrom(new InternetAddress(owner, "Example.com Admin"));
            InternetAddress to = new InternetAddress(toAddress);
            mess.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
            mess.setSubject(sub);
            mess.setContent(mp);

            Multipart mp1 = new MimeMultipart();

            String example = "Convert Java String";
            byte[] pdf1 = example.getBytes();
            // Attaching first pdf
            MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
            attachment.setFileName("pdf1.pdf");
            DataSource src = new ByteArrayDataSource(pdf1, "application/pdf"); 
            attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(src));
            mp1.addBodyPart(attachment);
            mess.setContent(mp1);
            Transport.send(mess);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Unihedron please debugg the code or tell me the error

Comment: What does "failed to load" mean?  Did you get the attachment, saved it in a file, and you couldn't display it using your pdf viewer?

Comment: @BillShannon i got the the file as attachment with .pdf but the pdf could load it

Comment: Save the attachment and compare the file to the file you sent.  Are they the same size?  Same contents?

Comment: In rare cases, JavaMail will choose the wrong encoding for some pdf files.  Try using the [attachFile](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to attach the file - attachment.attachFile("pdf1.pdf", "application/pdf", "base64");